# How to increment a <span> value by 1 everyday

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to be able to increment a number value within a  everyday as soon as it hit's midnight. So I'm assuming it would use the date() and jQuery?

Here is the current static code I have:

```
<div class="chart">
            <div class="percentage" data-percent="107"><span>107</span></div>
            <div class="label">Coffees in 2013</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Calculate the number of days between Jan. 1st and today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-jquery Probably better done server-side though.

Comment: In your example, where does the number "107" come from?

Comment: You can use the javascript own date class

Comment: @MarcAudet I just calculated it using a website. It's how many days have passed in 2013.

Comment: Would this work on it's own? var diff =  Math.floor(( Date.parse(str2) - Date.parse(str1) ) / 86400000);

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use server side datatime or access the time by finding the region of request (could be through ip) as the machine time by javascript could could be different from actual time.